# Add node to front of a link list

Tags: c#, data-structures

I am working with a simple link list.  I am trying to create a method that will insert an item to the front of my link list.

This Method works:

```
// Works
public static LinkedListNode AddItemAtFrontWorkingVersion(LinkedListNode node, int value)
{
  var newNode = new LinkedListNode(value);
  newNode.next = node;
  return newNode;
}
```

Called by:

```
LinkedListNode a = new LinkedListNode(5);
a = LinkedListNode.AddItemAtFrontWorkingVersion(a, 99);
```

Now I have a different version which doesn't work and i cant figure out why.  The list is an object so it should be on the heap why cant i just set to the new node.  When the method returns it is not changed.

Question:  Why do I have to return the node why cant I just assign it like I am in AddItemAtEnd?

```
// Does Not work
public static void AddItemAtFront(LinkedListNode node, int value)
{
    var newNode = new LinkedListNode(value);
    newNode.next = node;
    node = newNode;
}
```

Called by:

```
LinkedListNode a = new LinkedListNode(5);
LinkedListNode.AddItemAtFront(a, 99);
```

Full code:

```
using System;

namespace DataStructure
{

    public class LinkedListNode
    {

        public int value;
        public LinkedListNode next;

        public LinkedListNode(int value)
        {
            this.value = value;
        }

        public static void AddItemAtEnd(LinkedListNode node, int value) {

            var list = node.next;

            while (node.next != null)
            {
                node = node.next;                
            }
            node.next = new LinkedListNode(value);
        }

        // Does Not work
        public static void AddItemAtFront(LinkedListNode node, int value)
        {
            var newNode = new LinkedListNode(value);
            newNode.next = node;
            node = newNode;
        }

        // Works
        public static LinkedListNode AddItemAtFrontWorkingVersion(LinkedListNode node, int value)
        {
            var newNode = new LinkedListNode(value);
            newNode.next = node;
            return newNode;
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            LinkedListNode a = new LinkedListNode(5);
            LinkedListNode.AddItemAtFront(a, 99);
            a = LinkedListNode.AddItemAtFrontWorkingVersion(a, 99);
            LinkedListNode.AddItemAtEnd(a, 9);
            LinkedListNode.AddItemAtEnd(a, 10);
            LinkedListNode.AddItemAtEnd(a, 11);
            LinkedListNode.AddItemAtEnd(a, 12);
            LinkedListNode.AddItemAtFront(a, 99);

            a = LinkedListNode.AddItemAtFrontWorkingVersion(a, 99);
            Console.Read();
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Because you're assigning to a parameter. Note that ´AddItemAtEnd` doesn't modify `a` either, despite your assigning different values to the `node` parameter. Read about reference parameters in your favourite book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing your `LinkedListNode` by value. For your second version to be working you have to pass it by *reference*.

```
public static void AddItemAtFront(ref LinkedListNode node, int value)
{
    var newNode = new LinkedListNode(value);
    newNode.next = node;
    node = newNode;
}
```

More details may be found inside the documentation: [Passing Reference-Type Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-reference-type-parameters) .

Comment: Cant believe  i didn't think of that.